# Blocked while scraping goodreads.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, http-headers, robots.txt

I am trying to scrape a large sample (100k+) of the books available at "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/", but I get continuously blocked.
So far I have tried to implement the following solutions in my code:

- Check the robots.txt to find what sites/elements are not accessible
- Specify a header or multiple headers that randomly change
- Use multiple working proxies to avoid being blocked
- Set a delay up to 20 seconds between each scraping iteration that uses 10 simultaneous threads

Here is a simplified version of the code that gets blocked while trying to scrape only the title and author of the book, without using multiple simultaneous threads:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import random

proxies_list = ["http://89.71.193.86:8080", "http://178.77.206.21:59298", "http://79.106.37.70:48550",
                "http://41.190.128.82:47131", "http://159.224.109.140:38543", "http://94.28.90.214:37641",
                "http://46.10.241.140:53281", "http://82.147.120.30:56281", "http://41.215.32.86:55561"]
proxies = {"http": random.choice(proxies_list)}

# real header
# headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}

# multiple headers
headers_list = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.38 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1623.0 Safari/537.36',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36']
headers = {"user-agent": random.choice(headers_list)}

first_url = 1
last_url = 10000     # Last book is 8,630,000
sleep_time = 20

for book_reference_number in range(first_url, last_url):
    try:
        goodreads_html = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/" + str(book_reference_number), timeout=5, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
        doc = html.fromstring(goodreads_html.text)
        book_title = doc.xpath('//div[@id="topcol"]//h1[@id="bookTitle"]')[0].text.strip(", \t\n\r")
        try:
            author_name = doc.xpath('//div[@id="topcol"]//a[@class="authorName"]//span')[0].text.strip(", \t\n\r")
        except:
            author_name = ""
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        print(str(book_reference_number), book_title, author_name)
    except:
        print(str(book_reference_number) + " cannot be scraped.")
        pass
```

Comment: I'm with Goodreads 

Comment: Did you manage to scrape Goodreads? I always get blocked even if I try to use selenium..

Comment: I meant that I support Goodreads in this conflict. I've built crawlers indeed, but they (a) never pretend to be human; (b) announce themselves; (c) obey `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to scrape large database then i will recommend selenium, chances of being blocked will be low, and stable. NO need `time.sleep()`(time delay but you can add to make it more stable). Check the code below...

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
##copy chromedriver into python folder
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.set_window_position(-2000,0)#this function will minimize the window
first_url = 1
last_url = 10000     # Last book is 8,630,000

for book_reference_number in range(first_url, last_url):
    driver.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/"+str(book_reference_number))
    #time.sleep(2)#optional
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    try:
        book_title = soup.select('.gr-h1.gr-h1--serif')[0].text.strip()
    except:
        book_title = ''
    try:
        author_name = soup.select('.authorName')[0].text.strip()
    except:
        author_name = ''

    print('NO.', book_reference_number, 'TITLE: ', book_title, 'AUTHOR: ', author_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was thinking about selenium as last resort. Hope that scraping more than 100,000 will not take too long. Still wondering why goodreads.com cannot be scraped in any way with the usual requests library

Comment: I have not checked your code, but i assume you are sending too many requests in short period of time...also some website has some anti scraping mechanism to prevent bot/scraping. That's why i suggest selenium (you can run selenium in headless mode). And i don't see any difference between requests and selenium  .Unless you use multi-threading!

Answer (score 2):

What kind of proxies are these? Free proxies are dead on arrival for tasks on this scale, and I haven't had much luck with data center proxies either if the site is vigilant. You might want to try using residential proxies instead. Those do a better of hiding/bypassing device fingerprinting that might be exposing your script as a bot. Also consider setting up retries in case one fails.

### Reference:

1. [What is a residential proxy?](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-what-is-a-residential-proxy)
2. [Differences between Datacenter and Residential Proxies](https://get.brightdata.com/gm-differences-between-datacenter-and-residential-proxies)